# Why does this code returns Unit, whereas I expect it to return some other values?

Tags: scala

```
class Account {
    val id = Account.newUniqueNumber()
    private var balance = 0.0
    def deposit(amount: Double) { balance += amount }
}

object Account {
    private var lastNumber = 0
    private def newUniqueNumber() {
        lastNumber += 1; lastNumber
    }
}

var a1 = new Account()
var a2 = new Account()
println(a1.id)
println(a2.id)

~/myScala % scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
~/myScala % scala Account.scala
()
()
~/myScala %
```

I was expecting 1,2 as the output... My reasoning is...
    1. A new Account object is constructed
    2. While initialising the id field, the companion object is constructed (only once)

So the newUniqueNumber() call should have returned 1 and 2...

Any pointers?

Thanks..

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. While in the end the problem has to do with a missing equal sign, there is more to it than is asked in the other question.

Answer (score 6):

The method `newUniqueNumber` should return something and therefore you need to add an equal sign to its signature:

```
private def newUniqueNumber() = {
  lastNumber += 1
  lastNumber
}
```

Without it, it returns `Unit` which is similar to Java `void` and is printed as `()`.